# SpyderKernelAppnWARNING | No such comm: 2ed06aee37e411eb867974e5f9ff3c18 (OPENCV)

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, anaconda, spyder

I applied following codes

```
import cv2

img = cv2.imread("messi5.jpg", 0) # 0 = grayscale

cv2.imshow("First Photo", img)
```

and I received that error...

```
[SpyderKernelApp] WARNING | No such comm: 2ed06aee37e411eb867974e5f9ff3c18
```

[image]

How can I solve this problem? I updated spyder to 4.1.5 but it still is getting error...

Comment: SOLVED!!  If you have same problem like me, you need to add ending of your code cv2.waitKey()

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer, then mark it as accepted. Don’t write “solved” in the title.

Answer (score 1):

Use `cv2.waitKey(0)` for the window to be displayed until you press another key.